# SIGSEGV signal while sorting array with big amount of elements

Tags: c, sorting

I have array filled with 100000 elements (of integer) and I want to sort it using quicksort. It works when I fill this array with random numbers, but when I fill it like this

```
for(i=0; i<size/2; i++)
{
    tablica[i]= i;
}
for(i=size/2; i<size; i++)
{
    tablica[i]=size-i-1;
}
```

I get SIGSEGV signal and my app get crashed. I'm sure that my quicksort function is fine. When I fill this array with random, ascending or descending numbers everything works, even with more elements in array (like 100000000). I inicialize array like this:

```
int *tablica = calloc(size, sizeof (int));
```

Here is my quicksort code

```
void quicksort(int tab[], int lewy, int prawy)
{
int pivot = tab[(prawy+lewy)/2];
int p = prawy;
int l = lewy;
do
{
    while (tab[l] < pivot)
    {
        l++;
    }
    while (tab[p] > pivot)
    {
        p--;
    }
    if (l <= p)
    {
        int temp = tab[l];
        tab[l] = tab[p];
        tab[p] = temp;
        l++; p--;
    }
} while (l <= p);

if(p>lewy)
{
    quicksort(tab,lewy,p);
}
if(l<prawy)
{
    quicksort(tab,l,prawy);
}
}
```

And example of main function

```
int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int i;
int *tablica;
float start, stop, czas;
tablica = calloc(size, sizeof (int));
int *tab = calloc(size, sizeof (int));
for(i=0; i<size/2; i++)
{
    tablica[i]= i;
}
for(i=size/2; i<size; i++)
{
    tablica[i]=size-i-1;
}
start = clock();
quicksort(tablica,0,size-1);
stop = clock();
czas = (stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
free(tablica);
free(tab);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `calloc()` to make sure that you actually were allocated the amount you asked for? "If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned.
" from the `calloc()` man page.

Comment: Include a complete minimal example.

Comment: If `calloc` successfully allocates an array, then the above code should not segfault.

Comment: Here's a complete and minimal example with your snippet in it, and it works just fine: http://ideone.com/abXP7h

If you have valgrind, try running it under that and you'll see there's no invalid memory access.

Comment: Is it your quicksort function that crashes, or the code you posted? Why are you sure that your quicksort function is fine?

Comment: I added my quicksort function and example of main function to main post. calloc() returns everything ok.

Comment: `if (l <= p)` is suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm sure that my quicksort function is fine.

It's probably recursive, isn't it? What you're seeing is most likely a stack overflow, caused by too deeply nested recursion. Quick sort is especially weak in this respect, depending on the selection of the pivot and the distribution of the values.

Example: An array of size `8`, filled in the way you specified:

```
0 1 2 3 3 2 1 0
```

Let's take the first value as pivot, thus after partioning we might get:

```
0|0|1 2 3 3 2 1
```

See what happened? We only managed to get a single number into the left part. Quick sort on the right part won't be any better:

```
1 2 3 3 2 1
```

We take the first as pivot as before and partition:

```
1|1|2 3 3 2
```

And so on.

In every step you just get 2 elements sorted (the pivot and the single element for the left part) ... thus for an array of 100000 numbers you'd need 50000 steps to get it sorted. Each step is a recursive call. That's far too much for the (call) stack to take.

To alleviate the danger for such a pattern to occur you should adjust the [choice of your pivot value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot).

---

From the added quicksort code:

```
int pivot = tab[(prawy+lewy)/2];
```

You're selecting always the value in the mid of the range you're sorting. In the first iteration, this will be `size/2 -1`, and since there's no value larger than that (due to how the array is initialized) the right part will be (almost) empty, causing a similar pattern as I showed above.

Hint: Just try your code with a smaller size (e.g. `8`), and print the array the quick sort is working with on each call:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0 // (1)
0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
0, 1, 2, 0, 1
0, 1, 1, 0 // (2)
0, 0 // right part from (2)
3, 3 // right part from (1)
```

([Ideone](http://ideone.com/rCqg0l))